# ActiveMQ - 5.9.0: User authentication doesn't work from Client

Tags: activemq-classic

Currently ActiveMQ server accepts any username, password I supply from ActiveMQConnectionFactory. **User authentication** doesn't work.

In JAVA I used this:

```
String messageBrokerUrl = "tcp://localhost:61616";
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin", "xyz", messageBrokerUrl); 
connection.start();
this.session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
DestinationSource ds = connection.getDestinationSource();
Set<ActiveMQQueue> queues = ds.getQueues();
```

As you can see username password combination do not match. Still works for me.
Username: admin, password: admin is the correct combination.

Thanks.

Comment: You just created a factory instance, you would need to use it to create a connection and then the security may then kick in and fail

Comment: I have been doing all that from the start. It doesn't fail. Just updated the question. Pls check.

Comment: You are using a very old AMQ version - try making a mistake in the xml file to ensure its read by the broker.

Comment: I downloaded the latest AciveMQ - 5.9.0. Same issue. Do you know how we configure user authentication on server? I couldn't find any good resource explaining that.